# How do I escape spaces for the ftype command in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

I've created a new file type containing spaces and have specified the open command for it:

```
assoc .php="PHP Script"
ftype "PHP Script"="c:\program files (x86)\php\php.exe" -f "%1" -- %~2
```

So far so good, but now I'm unable to check which command is used to open files of this type:

```
ftype "PHP Script"
File type 'PHP' not found or no open command associated with it.
```

I've tried using [the caret symbol](https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks), to no effect. How do I get ftype to accept spaces for retrieving the command currently in use?

Comment: +1, interesting question! I didn't even know ProgIDs could contain spaces before this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. First, some background reading on MSDN:

- [File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How to Register a File Type for a New Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Programmatic Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

When you use `assoc .ext=fileType`, that **fileType** is actually the **ProgID**. As the last link above states:

> The proper format of a ProgID key name is [Vendor or Application].[Component].[Version], **separated by periods and with *no spaces***, as in Word.Document.6. The Version portion is optional but strongly recommended.

The file type description you can add as a **FriendlyTypeName** value in the registry.

For example:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="txtfile"
"PerceivedType"="text"
"Content Type"="text/plain"
```

Here **.txt** is obviously the extension and the **(Default)** value is set to the ProgID i.e. **txtfile**.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile]
@="Text Document"
"FriendlyTypeName"="Text Document"
```

Here for the ProgID we have the **(Default)** value set to the file type description, and same for **FriendlyTypeName**. In general though the latter is used to display localised string resources and must be formatted as an indirect string (a fully qualified file name and resource value preceded by the @ symbol, for instance `@%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe,-469` for **txtfile**).

---

I don't know why `assoc` and `ftype` both allow you to use spaces in the fileType/ProgID strings, since that goes against MS' own guidelines. ProgIDs with spaces even work properly if created manually in the registry (I just tested), but significantly I found not a single ProgID created by any program that uses spaces. Stranger still is how `ftype` seems to reject spaces while *getting* data (quotes don't help), whereas it has no problems accepting them while *setting* the command string in the first place (quotes aren't even required while setting).

My guess is someone forgot to inform the `ftype` devs of this discrepancy, because I couldn't figure out a way to make the command retrieve the command string it had itself set previously for a ProgID containing spaces. My advice? Stick to the guidelines, don't use spaces in ProgIDs and save yourself the grief of trying to figure out Windows' quirks.

Comment: +1.  For the record, though, there's a workaround: `ftype | findstr /c:"PHP Script"`

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Nice! Didn't even think of find/findstr, which of course will work since `ftype` by itself enumerates all the registered types.

Comment: or `ftype | grep "PHP Script"`, if you have [gnuwin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) installed. At least I can say that `less` is invaluable if working in windows' command line.

Comment: It's too bad M$ doesn't give scripts that do it right, right out of the box.   :(