# How do I get a file type to show up with a name I choose in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, window

I associated a file extension using the command `assoc`.  But in the Explorer, it lists the type as the extension name.  I.e. `assoc .sh=ShellScript` will still cause explorer to show the type as `SH File`.

Anyway to change it so it shows up as `ShellScript` or better yet, `Shell Script`?

EDIT:

Using `assoc` didn't work. Seems to be something wrong with my registry.  I figured that using quotes would put in a white space, but because it didn't show up in the explorer, I figured it may have been part of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you do *not* add spaces to the **ProgID** (that's the string on the right side of the equals sign when you use *assoc*), even though *assoc* and *ftype* may (partially) support it. Read my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/605648/138343) for details.

The proper way to do it is to use a ProgID without spaces, and to set the **(Default)** as well as the **FriendlyTypeName** for the ProgID to the description you want via the registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="txtfile"
"PerceivedType"="text"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile]
@="Text Document"
"FriendlyTypeName"="Text Document"
```

If all that registry editing seems too complex to you, you can easily use something like [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to set the **Description** as follows:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

I just experimented myself with the assoc command, it turns out the Explorer shows exactly what I put after the equal sign as file type. I'm also on Windows 7.
Maybe you can try log out and log in again.

For adding the space in the middle, you can quote the name.

```
assoc .sh="Shell Script"
```

Comment: Hrm, you're right. Must have broken something in the registry. It worked with another unused extension.  Now how to fix...?

Comment: @Adrian Besides editing the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, you may try this little [application](http://izt.name/apps/types/) suggested by a MVP in this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-set-file-associations-in-windows-7-not-open/e3470b2d-385c-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5). You can edit names of each extension.

Answer (score 0):

you done right, 
just put double quotes if you want space between two words,
i have tried on my laptop,

> assoc .foo="Foo bar file"

and it just works, immediately,

if still not changing run `cmd.exe` as an `Administrator`
otherwise it will display `Access Denied.`

CMD output :

```
C:\Windows\System32\>assoc .bar="Foo bar file"
.bar=Foo bar file
```